# Derivative of $vec(AA^T)$ w.r.t. $A$, where $A$ is a vector

Tags: calculus, matrices

Let $A$ a $n \times 1 $ vector. What is the derivative of $ vec(AA^T) $ w.r.t. $A$?

Update: I started from $vec(AA^T) = vec(I_n A A^T I_N) = (A \otimes I_N) vec(A) = vec(I_N \otimes A) vec(A^T)$.

Applying the chain rule, the derivative w.r.t $vec(A)$ equals $(A \otimes I_N) + vec(I_N \otimes A) T$, where $T$ is an operator such that $vec(A^T) = T vec(A)$.

However, what I want is the derivative w.r.t. $A$, not $vec(A)$. The problem appears kind of trivial, but I cannot wrap my head around it.

Comment: By $vec(AA^T)$, do you mean the $(n \times n)$ matrix $A \times A^T$? It is not clear.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Yes, $vec(AA^T)$ means the vectorized $n \times n$ matrix $A \times A^T$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Done!

Comment: $vec(aa^T)=vec(a1a^T)=(a\otimes a)vec(1)=a\otimes a$. The differential is $d vec(aa^T)=da\otimes a+a\otimes da$

Comment: Excellent, thanks! And how do we get to the gradient from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$If you consider the map
\begin{align*}
m \colon \R^{n} &\longrightarrow \R^{n\times n}, \\
\mathbf v &\longmapsto \mathbf v\mathbf v^T,
\end{align*}
its total derivative at $\mathbf v$ is the linear map
\begin{align*}
\mathrm D_{\mathbf v} m \colon \R^{n} &\longrightarrow \R^{n\times n}, \\
\mathbf z &\longmapsto \mathbf v\mathbf z^T + \mathbf z\mathbf v^T.
\end{align*}
Vectorizing this result you have the map $\widetilde m\colon \R^{n}\to \R^{n^2}$ sending $\mathbf v$ to $\operatorname{vec}(\mathbf v\mathbf v^T)$ and its total derivative at $\mathbf v$ is given by

### $$
\mathbf z \longmapsto \operatorname{vec}(\mathbf v\mathbf z^T + \mathbf z\mathbf v^T).
$$

Informally speaking, when $\mathbf x = \operatorname{vec}(\mathbf v\mathbf v^T)$, you have
$$
\mathrm d\mathbf x = \operatorname{vec}\Big(\mathbf v (\mathrm d \mathbf v)^T + (\mathrm d \mathbf v) \mathbf v^T\Big).
$$
Using Kronecker products you might write $\operatorname{vec}(\mathbf v\mathbf w^T)$ as $\mathbf v\otimes \mathbf w$ so that $\mathbf x = \mathbf v\otimes \mathbf v$ and
$$
\mathrm d\mathbf x = \mathbf v\otimes \mathrm d\mathbf v + \mathrm d \mathbf v \otimes \mathbf v.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\def\v{{\rm vec}}\def\d{{\rm diag}}\def\D{{\rm Diag}}\def\p{{\partial}}\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3^T}}$To
minimize confusion, let's use lowercase letters to denote vectors, i.e. $A\to a$.

Expand the `vec()` operator using Kronecker products in two different ways.

Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= \v(aa^T) \\
 &\doteq \left(I\otimes a\right)a \;=\; \left(a\otimes I\right)a \\
df &= \left(I\otimes a\right)da + \left(a\otimes I\right)da \\
   &= \left(I\otimes a+a\otimes I\right)da \\
\grad{f}{a}
   &= I\otimes a+a\otimes I \\
}$$
Note that, unlike a matrix, for a *vector* argument  $\;\v(a^T)=\v(a)$.